# 6-bit binary counter in C (compiles, but then Windows encounters error)

Tags: c, debugging

I am extremely new to C and trying to make a 6-bit binary counter, where each return has all 6 digits listed (i.e 000000, 000001,...). Currently, my solution compiles but does not execute once compiled (I get a warning that says something to the effect of "A problem caused Windows to stop working" and then no output is displayed). If anyone could help figure out why this happens, or suggest a better way to do this since I know my approach is extremely convoluted, I'd appreciate the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

long * convert(long dec){

   if(dec == 0){

      return 0;

   }else{

      return(long *)(dec % 2 + (10 * *convert(dec / 2)));

   }

}

char* long_enough(char* num){

   char* have_one = "0000";

   char* have_two = "0000";

   char* have_three = "000";

   char* have_four = "00";

   char* have_five = "0";   

   if(strlen(num) == 2){

      strcat(have_one, num);

   }else if(strlen(num) == 3){

      strcat(have_two, num);

   }else if(strlen(num) == 4){

      strcat(have_three, num);

   }else if(strlen(num) == 5){

      strcat(have_four, num);

   }else if(strlen(num) == 6){

      strcat(have_five, num);

   }

}      

char main(){

   int i;

   int count = -1;

   printf("\n");

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){

      count++;

      long* binNum = (long *)(convert(count));

      char* new;

      char done = sprintf(new, "%d", binNum);

      long_enough((char *)(intptr_t)done); 

      printf("%s\n", long_enough((char *)(intptr_t)done));      


   }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run"?  Throws an error, for example?

Comment: In your convert function, change all the occurrences of `long *` to just plain `long`. And in your `main` function, all those casts should be telling you that you're overlooking something fundamental.

Comment: One of your first adventures into C is attempting a recursive algorithm?  That is asking for issues.  I'd consider trying a simple loop to do what you want here.  The (or one of the) problem is your convert function is working with actual long values, but returning those longs as pointers, which is a bad idea.  Also, calling a char * "new" is not a good idea either as it is a reserved word in C++ (just in case).

Comment: `long_enough` does not return value. and You can not combine strings into string literals.

Comment: You call `strlen` on an invalid pointer (amongst other things)

Comment: you call strcat with the first pointer pointing to non-writable memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a `long*` to point nowhere?
It makes no sense. A pointer is meant to point to a memmory region and this memory region must have been allocated (either stack or heap).

It makes no sense that you are multiplying a binary number by 10 either.

You need to clarify your thought.

When you say you are making a "binary counter", think first about what it means. Given the code you posted, it looks like you should split your problem in two parts:

1. Count in binary.
2. Show the value in a human readable manner.

Once you've splitted the problem in two, I'll help you with one and let the other on your own.

**Convert a number into binary:**

Well, computer numbers are already binary by construction. Let's suppose you need, for any didactic reason, to reinvent the wheel in such a way that you can address individual values.

You have basically two options: use an `array` or use a `bit-mask`.

By using an `array` you'll waste more memory but printing the result will be easier.

By using a `bit-mask` you basically will have to allocate a single integer (or even `char` since you just need 6 bits) and shift it left while testing the original number.

```
// Example using bit-masks / bit-shifts into an uchar.
unsigned char to_bin6( unsigned int number )
{
    unsigned char bin6 = 0;

    // Left align and Clear out extra bits since we only care about the lowest 6.
    number <<= ( 8 * sizeof( unsigned int ) ) - 6;

    for ( int count = 6; count; --count )
        bin6 <<= number;

    return bin6;
}
```

Now with arrays.

```
// Example using char array.
// Array needs to have an additional element for the EoS (end of string) marker.
void to_bin6( unsigned int number, unsigned char bin6[ 7 ] )
{
     // Fills the output buffer in the same direction you'd expect to read.
    for ( int count = 5; count >= 0; --count )
        bin6[ count ] = ( number & ( 1 << count ) ) ?
                        '1' : '0';    // Feeds character '1' or '0' according to bit value.
    bin6[ 6 ] = '\0'; // EoS: Note this is NOT the same as '0'.
}
```

**Show a number as binary for human reading:**

That's the part I'll leave for you.

*Hint: using array it is very easy.*

Tell me if you need more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with your handling of pointers.  [@Pete Becker suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283439/6-bit-binary-counter-in-c-compiles-but-doesnt-run#comment73635158_43283439) should get get you started but what also jumped out at me was this line:

```
 return(long *)(dec % 2 + (10 * *convert(dec / 2)));
```

Here you are multiplying by the raw memory of the convert function result. If your intent is to raise to a power, note that there is no exponent operator in C.  Do raise to a power, you'll need to `#include <math.h>` and use the `pow(x,e)` function.

You'll definitely want to read up on the pointer and value semantics in C.  I'd recommend the book *The C Programming Language* by  Brian W. Kernighan & Dennis M. Ritchie (the creators of the language).  It is concise and will likely get you further, faster than a lot of the other books out there.

Comment: Thanks @chux for cleaning up my first attempt to answer a question on SF.  I'm reading the formatting guidelines now